# Chrome extension timer - API issue?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Pomodoro timer program, and I can't figure out how to keep the timer running in the background, after I unfocus the popup. 
I've been working on this for a bit, but I currently have all the code for the actual timer in the background script. I was hoping to use the runtime API in popup.js to send a one-time message to start the timer in background.js, and then whenever the user opens the extension, to return what the timer is set to.

I'm also not entirely sure I'm approaching the question correctly.

The code wasn't working, so I simplified it down to just sending the message and trying to get a response, which I found is the problem.

Code: 
**popup.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: 'hello'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell)
});
```

**background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == 'hello') {
      sendResponse({farewell: 'goodbye'})
      toggleClock();
    }
  });

//working toggleClock() function
```

**manifest.json:**

```
"browser_action": {
        "default_popup":"popup.html",
        "default_title":"Flexidoro",
        "default_icon":"flexidoro.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },


    "permissions": [ "storage", "alarms" ]
```

There aren't any errors in the extension error log, and there also isn't anything in the console.

 
Am I taking the right approach? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sarah, there are 3 console logs - Page, background and popup each have their own - your log step is in the  popup.js so i assume you've checked your message there?  (additionally, i when doing this "first step" stuff, alerts work better so you don't miss them - easy enoguh to change to logs when you're happy it's working right)  .... Something to try is stick a `return true;` at the end of the  `onMesssage.AddLister` (but outside the if) - see if that helps return the message